# Linux command to dynamically convert the GB into MB

Tags: linux, shell

I need to write a script to show the Total Swap Size, Used Swap Size and % used.

Below are the commands, I'm using.

```
pgsize=`swapon | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}'`

pgused=`swapon | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'`

pgpercent=$(($pgused * 100/ $pgsize))
```

The output of the commands are
**pgsize** = 16G
**pgused** = 22M
**pgpercent** - I'm getting the below error in this line

**22M: value too great for base (error token is "22M")**

Here, how do I need to convert the 22M into 22 and 16G into 16*1024 and divide it. For eg. (22*100)/(16*1024)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print the percentage used of the last swap area listed by swapon:

```
swapon --bytes --show=USED,SIZE | awk 'END{print 100*$1/$2}'
```

To save it in a variable:

```
ppgpercent=$(/sbin/swapon --bytes --show=USED,SIZE | awk 'END{print 100*$1/$2}')
```

Answer (score 3):

`swapon` has a `--bytes` parameter

hence:

> swapon --raw --bytes  | tail -1 | awk '{print $4 "/" $3}' | bc